# encode x264(libx264) raw yuv frame data

Tags: c++, c, x264, libx264

I am trying to encode an MP4 video using raw YUV frames data, but I am not sure how can I fill the plane data (preferably without using other libraries like ffmpeg)

The frame data is already encoded in I420, and does not need conversion.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
const char *frameData = /* Raw frame data */;

x264_t *encoder = x264_encoder_open(&param);
x264_picture_t imgInput, imgOutput;
x264_picture_alloc(&imgInput, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);

// how can I fill the struct data of imgInput

x264_nal_t *nals;
int i_nals;
int frameSize = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &imgInput, &imgOutput);
```

The equivalent command line that I have found is :

```
 x264 --output video.mp4 --fps 15 --input-res 1280x800 imgdata_01.raw
```

But I could not figure out how the app does it.

Thanks.

Comment: @mpromonet I have checked the question, but the examples are using `swscale`, and also do not provide a way to map existing YUV data to x264_picture_t.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at libx264 API usage [example](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=example.c;hb=HEAD). This example use fread() to fill frame allocated by x264_picture_alloc() with actual i420 data from stdin. If you already have i420 data in memory and want to skip memcpy step than instead of it you can:

1. Use x264_picture_init() instead of x264_picture_alloc() and x264_picture_clean(). Because you don't need allocate memory on heap for frame data.
2. Fill x264_picture_t.img struct fields:

   - i_csp = X264_CSP_I420;
   - i_plane = 3;
   - plane[0] = pointer to Y-plane;
   - i_stride[0] = stride in bytes for Y-plane;
   - plane[1] = pointer to U-plane;
   - i_stride[1] = stride in bytes for U-plane;
   - plane[2] = pointer to V-plane;
   - i_stride[2] = stride in bytes for V-plane;

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer above, this is an example to fill an `x264_picture_t` image.

```
int fillImage(uint8_t* buffer, int width, int height, x264_picture_t*pic){
    int ret = x264_picture_alloc(pic, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);
    if (ret < 0) return ret;
    pic->img.i_plane = 3; // Y, U and V
    pic->img.i_stride[0] = width;
    // U and V planes are half the size of Y plane
    pic->img.i_stride[1] = width / 2;
    pic->img.i_stride[2] = width / 2;
    int uvsize = ((width + 1) >> 1) * ((height + 1) >> 1);
    pic->img.plane[0] = buffer; // Y Plane pointer
    pic->img.plane[1] = buffer + (width * height); // U Plane pointer
    pic->img.plane[2] = pic->img.plane[1] + uvsize; // V Plane pointer
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Use of x264_picture_alloc is wrong here because: 1) you don't need it and should use x264_picture_init instead; 2) there is no define for pic_in in you example; 3) x264_picture_alloc have int (error code) as return.